# What did Jesus mean in Luke 18 vs 25

Tags: bible, exegesis

Indeed it is easier for a camel to go through the eye of a needle than for someone who is rich to enter the kingdom of God (NIV)

Is this a straight foward verse or he was meaning only that rich man